Next-auth credentials provider doesn`t get token and it's redirecting wrong
I am using Next-Auth, but it`s not getting token and it's redirecting wrong.
That is my LoginForm
import { signIn } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation';
import { FormEvent } from 'react';

export default function LoginForm() {
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()
    const error = searchParams.get('error')

    async function handleLogin(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> | undefined) {
        event?.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData(event?.currentTarget);
        const data = {
            email: formData.get('email'),
            password: formData.get('password')
        }

        await signIn("Credentials", {
            ...data,
            callbackUrl: '/dashboard',
        })
    }

    return (
//...

That is my Route.ts
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const nextAuthOptions: NextAuthOptions = {

    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                try {
                    const res = await fetch(process.env.NEXTAUTH_API + '/api/CreateToken', 
{
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            email: credentials?.email,
                            password: credentials?.password
                        }),
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                    });


                    const user = await res.json()
                    cookies().set("jwt", user.jwt);

                    if (user) {
                        return user
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        })
    ],

    pages: {
        signIn: '/'
    }
}

const handler = NextAuth(nextAuthOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }

When I try to login the page is redirected to:
http://localhost:3000/?callbackUrl=https%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A3000%2Fdashboard
without jwt response.
Could you help please?
